# Datasets for calculation of exoplanet properties

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, exoplanets

I would like to create program for calculation exoplanet properties, but I only found transit dataset from Kepler on NASA website. From light curve I can calculate:

- planet radius $r$ from $\frac{r_{planet}^2}{R_{star}^2} = brightness\ drop$,
- semi-major axis $a$ from $p^2 = a^3\frac{4\pi^2}{G(m_{planet} + M_{star})}$,
- orbital period from period of transits.

But what about mass? Is there any public dataset of stars wavelength timeseries for radial velocity calculation?

Also, is there any way to calculate information about exoplanet atmosphere? I read that you can find out elements in atmosphere by comparing star light spectrum and star light spectrum during planet transit. Is any data publicly available for this purpose?

Comment: http://exoplanets.org/table

Comment: @kleingordon Thank you, I see period and semiamplitude of radial velocity. There is also graph of radial velocity in time in detail (e. g. http://exoplanets.org/detail/HAT-P-27_b). Is there any way to obtain data for radial velocity as numbers (e. g. in csv) instead of image-graph?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know additional details about this resource.